# Protractor: addLocator() : 'Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll of null' '

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I trying to run standart example from Protractor's documentation ( http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator ). And have an Error: 'Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll of null'

```
    by.addLocator('buttonTextSimple',
    function(buttonText, opt_parentElement, opt_rootSelector  ) {
    var using = opt_parentElement,
        buttons = using.querySelectorAll('button');
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(buttons, function(button) {
        return button.textContent === buttonText;
        });
    });
```

View the same:

```
<button ng-click="doAddition()">Go!</button>
```

What I should do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare a variable called `using` like this:

```
var using = opt_parentElement || document;
```

so if there is no optional parent element provided, then global `document` will be used to query for results.

Not sure if it is a typo in the documentation or Protractor was expected to auto-fill `opt_parentElement` variable with some defaults if it is not being set.